# jquery template customizing

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using jquery template to display certain values. In it I am using if statement to check if age is old, depending upon the answer the  background color is changed. 
This code works fine without if statement, when I insert If statement and check it in Firebug it shows error "uncaught exception: Expected block tag" 
Please help Thanks.

```
<script id="humanTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
    <form id="form1" action ="">
       <table>
            <tbody>
                    {{#each items}}
                         <td>{{=name}}</td>
                        {{if {{=age}} == 'old' }}
                         <td style="background-color: red">{{=age}}</td>
                         {{ else }}
                          <td style="background-color: red">{{=age}}</td>
                           {{/if}} 
                         <td>{{=date}}</td>
                        <td><a href="javascript:fnProcess()">Action</a></td>
                     </tr>
                    {{/each}}    
                </tbody>                    
        </table>         
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the exact template language you're using, but it looks like this might be the problem:

```
{{if {{=age}} == 'old' }}
```

The `{{=age}}` notation looks like it's used to substitute the value of `age` into the output (based on how it's used elsewhere). But since you're already inside a `{{ }}` block, try this:

```
{{if age == 'old' }}
```